# Modifying playerlist scoreboard

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I want to change the list that is displayed when a player presses the tab key. I have used `player.setPlayerListName(ChatColor.GREEN +" new Name")` to change a player name and `player.setPlayerListHeaderFooter("header", "footer");` to set the header/footer displayed in this list.

Now I want to make different people see different player names in the list, this would be used to hide moderators in the tab list and show different roles in minigames.

My example: I have a minigame that contains different roles, but not everyone should be able to see them on the table list, only players who are on the same team should be able to see their team members. Let's say I have 3 teams:

- Team1 (2 players)
- Team2 (2 players)
- Team3 (2 players)

Everyone in Team1 should see their team members with their assigned team name in the table list. Everyone else would only be shown in white for Team1, so they cannot see which team they are on.

The same applies to Team2 and Team3.

*This is an example, there is no need to lecture the players.*

I've used ProtocolLib and Packets, in general, a few times so there shouldn't be a problem with it.
What should I use?
Thanks for your help :D

Comment: Which version of MC are you using ?

Comment: @Elikill58 1.16.5

Comment: Ok, and the scoreboard is on the right, you are talking about the TAB list ?

Comment: @Elikill58 i am talking about the TAB list / Player list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove a player from the TAB list, you should send  `PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo` packet, like that :

```
((CraftPlayer) player).getHandle().playerConnection.sendPacket(new PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo(PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo.EnumPlayerInfoAction.REMOVE_PLAYER, entityPlayerToAdd));
```

In your case, you will have something like that :

```
EntityPlayer ep = ((CraftPlayer) p).getHandle(); // the player to hide
PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo packet = new PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo(PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo.EnumPlayerInfoAction.REMOVE_PLAYER, ep);
for(Player all : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
    if(all != p && !Team.isSameTeam(all, p)) {
        ((CraftPlayer) all).getHandle().playerConnection.sendPacket(packet);
    }
});
```

Then, if you want to re-add them in TAB list, use :

```
((CraftPlayer) player).getHandle().playerConnection.sendPacket(new PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo(PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo.EnumPlayerInfoAction.ADD_PLAYER, entityPlayerToAdd));
```

If you want to have a complete wait to make a very great TAB, without take lot of time, there [TAB](https://github.com/NEZNAMY/TAB) plugin.

Then, if you want to hide completly a player (even when playing, not only tab), use this :

To **hide/show** player for others, you can use `Player.hidePlayer` ([Javadoc](https://helpch.at/docs/1.16.4/org/bukkit/entity/Player.html#hidePlayer(org.bukkit.plugin.Plugin,org.bukkit.entity.Player))) like that :

```
MyPlugin pl = MyPlugin.getInstance();
for(Player all : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
   // here you can add filter to make mod showed to admin
   all.hidePlayer(pl, all);
}
```

Don't forget to hide them when someone join, like that :

```
@EventHandler
public void onJoin(PlayerJoinEvent e) {
   Player p = e.getPlayer();
   for(Player vanished : getVanished()) {
      p.hidePlayer(MyPlugin.getInstance(), vanished);
   }
}
```

And use the same to show player with `Player.showPlayer` ([javadoc](https://helpch.at/docs/1.16.4/org/bukkit/entity/Player.html#showPlayer(org.bukkit.plugin.Plugin,org.bukkit.entity.Player)))

Comment: I can't just hide everyone, since everyone should still be able to see each other, but not on the tablist since I wanna modify it, so some people could see stuff like the player's role and some can't. I'm going to edit my post with an example

Comment: I edited my original post

Comment: Yes, I see. I just edit my answer, hope it's fine now !